# algorithm for finding closest images based on jitter / translation

Tags: image, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, similarity

I've got a series of images and in some of them the people are only slightly moved, or the camera was shifted slightly, but mostly all is still the same.

I'm wondering algorithmically how I could detect this and find and score images based on their closeness.

A simple euclidian distance might not work - imagine the case in where zebra stripes were shifted just enough to have the "old" white positions filled with black and vice versa. A pathological example, I know, but you get the idea.

As an optional tag along, perhaps there's a nice OpenCV or scipy (preference for Python) function for this or some of the pipeline for doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample images to help understand the problem?

Comment: Think of when you are clicking through a photo album and you see two photos that were taken just after one another -- that's probably the best example I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference between your images.
The higher the intensity values of the difference image, the more they are different.
So, if you have two exactly the same images and subtract them, there will be a "black" difference image.
You can simply use the overloaded `operator-()` of `Mat`-class.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, yes that's a valid idea, but with large enough translation, there's might not be much of a match up. I'm looking for something more clever, something analogous, for example, to SIFT.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the problem yet. Two example images would be helpful.